# Changing data in MySQL DB with prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm totaly new to MySQL and need some help in a project I got for home work. 
I need to create a bank system and working on my Client table,
I created the beans and the interface and working atm on the managers, I did the add new client function

But have no idea how to even start on the rest :

- updateClientDetails
- removeClient
- viewClientDetails

I was wondering if I can have a lead on how to even start those functions please :)

p.s
That's how I wrote the `addNewClient` method:

```
public void addNewClient(ClientsBean client) {


    try {                       
        System.out.println(connect);
        PreparedStatement ps = connect.getConnection().prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO mbank.clients VALUES"+
                "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setLong(1, client.getClient_id());
            ps.setString(2,client.getName());
            ps.setString(3, client.getPassword());

            String type = "GOLD";
            if (client.getType() == Type.GOLD) {
                type = Type.GOLD.name();
            } else if (client.getType() == Type.PLATINUM) {
                type = Type.PLATINUM.name();
            } else {
                type = Type.REGULAR.name();
            }
            ps.setString(4, type);
            ps.setString(5, client.getAddress());
            ps.setString(6, client.getEmail());
            ps.setString(7, client.getPhone());
            ps.setString(8, client.getComment());
            ps.execute();   
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Problem occurs during updatig cliant details");
    }       
}
```

Update: 
Ok so wanted to make the updateClientDetails function and I used some examples
I get syntax SQLexception not sure where I did wrong here and could use some help please ?
I want to update the account with the ID 66

```
public void updateClientDetails() {

    try {

        System.out.println(connect);
        PreparedStatement ps = connect.getConnection().prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE mbank.clients SET client_id = ?, client_name = ?, 
        password  = ?, type = ?, adress = ?, email = ?, phone = ?, comment = ?" +"WHERE client_id =66");
        ps.setLong(1, client.getClient_id());
        ps.setString(2,client.getName());
        ps.setString(3, client.getPassword());
        String type = "GOLD";
        if (client.getType() == Type.GOLD) {
            type = Type.GOLD.name();
        } else if (client.getType() == Type.PLATINUM) {
            type = Type.PLATINUM.name();
        } else {
            type = Type.REGULAR.name();
        }
        ps.setString(4, type);
        ps.setString(5, client.getAddress());
        ps.setString(6, client.getEmail());
        ps.setString(7, client.getPhone());
        ps.setString(8, client.getComment());
        ps.execute();   

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Problem occurs during updatig cliant details");
    }       
}
```

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 4) There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: Are you familiar with the SQL commands, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty good resource for learning MySQL is **w3schools**. You should read

1. [SELECT (viewClientDetails)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)
2. Then you should read (link is on the left side of the page) "SQL UPDATE" (updateClientDetails)
3. And "SQL DELETE" (removeClient)

You learn the most if you do your homework yourself.

Comment: I didn't know w3fools before but I think that the articles about the **basic SQL commands** (select, update, delete) are pretty accurate and easy to understand.